# Is there any personal information in the .git directory

Tags: git

If I just want to send a whole source directory as a tar-ball to somebody, can I include the .git or is there any personal information in there?

The perfect scenario would be for the other person to unpack the directory and start there own fork, so to speak, without any trace of me as a former "owner" except for my name in the commits. Is that possible?

Comment: why can`t the other person just git clone what you have somewhere in a git repository?

Comment: You should send them `only` the .git directory... no need to send the working directory above it.  Alternatively, you can host it on a site like bitbucket or github and have your friend fork it

Comment: I don't think there is any personal or password data stored in the .git directory but you should wait for an expert to confirm.  You could do a `git gc` first to get rid of any dangling references.  Also take a look at the `config` file under `.git` to make sure nothing sensitive is in there.  Make sure you didn't add any hooks that contain passwords etc (check the `hooks` directory)

Comment: It should be safe to delete everything under the `logs` directory, since your friend does not really need to know all of your checkout history

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the content of the [`.git/` directories](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html), it contains all information needed to keep track of changes on the repo, which is useful for the person you are leaving a copy for, either for logs and commits that occurred before, so in short there are no personal information.

Although there is the case that @HBHB and @tarleb mentioned, which is configuring your username locally per repo, which leaves this info in your `.git/config` file as show below:

```
 [core]
     repositoryformatversion = 0
     fileMode = false
     bare = false
     logallrefupdates = true
     ignorecase = true
     precomposeunicode = true
 [branch "master"]
     remote = origin
     merge = refs/heads/master
 [branch "development"]
     remote = origin
     merge = refs/heads/development
 [user]
     email = {your_email@example.com}
```

Comment: This is not necessarily true. You could have done a `git config user.email "your_email@example.com"` which would result in your email address being in the repository config file.

Comment: But this is coming from `.gitconfig` on your machine

Comment: It is only done globally if you pass the `--global` switch to the `git config` command. Otherwise, if you do it in your repository, it goes into `.git/config`. See: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git/

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab: Only if you configured git globally.  It's not unusual to use different mail addresses for different projects (think work vs private repos).

Answer (score 6):

@RabeeAbdelWahab covers it pretty well above.  Just to be a bit more specific: The `.git` directory contains info like

- personal git preferences for this repo (e.g. email, GPG key fingerprint, sometimes even a SMTP password (bad idea!)),
- your reflog history, including all recent commits even if they are no longer present in any branch,
- local gitignore preferences (`.git/info/exclude`).

It's usually not super sensitive information, but one might want to think twice about whether it's a good idea to sent that to somebody else.

As an alternative, I'd suggest to clone the repo into a new directory, alter the settings you wanted to preserve and send that new repo instead.